# Symfony new project issue

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install Symfony for the first time and when I try to create a new project, the system gives me an error.
When i use:

```
symfony new test
```

It leads to:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]                                                                      
Client error response [url] http://symfony.com/versions.json [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and followed symfony setup tutorial by the book, the installation worked fine, the only thing I had to do differently is to set the proxy configuration.

Can anyone provide some enlightenment on the issue?

[Update 1]
I tried to use "symfony demo", it shows up a similar error.

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: The php version is 7.0

Comment: what happens if you try to wget http://symfony.com/versions.json

Comment: Works normally.

Comment: did you set the `HTTP_PROXY` env variables accordingly? https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer#updating-the-installer

Comment: Yep, same error pops up.

Comment: try with sudo -E

Comment: Still getting the same error...

Comment: try creating new project with the terminal command: `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition your_project_name "3.0.*"`

Comment: That worked fine, thanks!